# Indoor positioning android app using wifi signals

Tags: android, android-studio

Am new to android ,i want to create an android app to track indoor position using ips(wifi signals) 
I need to know what are Prerequisites required for and the basic idea to develop it

Comment: i tried but couldn't get please send me the link

Comment: Where are you, what have you tried? Do you have a rudimantary app? Can you code? Because coding is definitely one of the prerequisites. Do you have a few apps that you built before? Information please!

Answer (score 1):

You must have:

1) some wiFi antennas working around (minimum three to have the precise position in the room);

2) you must use your Wifi and check the power of each antenna.

Depending on the variations of these three levels of power, you can understand where you are. This is called triangulation.